# aspnet5 - dnx-watch not added to path

Tags: path, asp.net-core, dnx

Probably missing something obvious, but...  After successfully installing dnx-watch via "dnu install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher --no-cache"

```
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher'
OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher' 101ms
Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher.1.0.0-rc1-final was added to project.json.
```

However, when trying to run "dnx-watch" I receive:

```
'dnx-watch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now, the package and realted files do exist under {user}.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher

I guess I expected it to be added to the path such that it is usable after install.  If I directly reference "{user}.dnx\packages\Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher\app\dnx-watch.cmd" in the dir containing my project.json I get:

```
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher'. Available commands: dnx-watch.
```

I'm using the dnx clr rc1-final

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher` instead, `dnx-watch` is not a usual package, it doesn't need to be added to project.